# Glympse won't update in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, glympse

I've working on an app that uses the GlympseLite SDK, but it's only sending location updates when the app is in the foreground. I noticed that the first time the app is run, when a Glympse is about to be started, this notification is displayed, but only for a very short time:

> **Location Services Disabled**
>
> Please enable location settings through the device 'Settings > Privacy > Location'.

Settings shows that location services are turned on, and the app appears in the list with location access set to `Always`.

I created a new app with just the Glympse functionality to rule out anything else, and I am presented with the same notification.

This is on an iPhone 6s, with iOS 9.3.1, but the issue also happens on simulated devices running other versions of iOS.

I've tried the sample apps provided with the SDK, and they seem to run in the background fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The Glympse Lite SDK is no longer available / supported, so you may want to consider switching to the full SDK. The Lite SDK is not receiving updates for things that may break it as new versions of iOS are released.

However, I do have suggestions to try.

Firstly, make sure you've requested background location updates in your application's plist. Here is the section that should be added:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

Also make sure this key is added to your plist.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Background location is required for sending Glympses.</string>
```